# Updating a table with information Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I am trying to make an application where users can enter data into a page filled with fields. Based off that information, a table will be updated with the information they enter. The problem is the table cant be updated as you need to start a SQL query with SELECT or WITH. Any idea on how to get around this? ex:

```
 UPDATE temptable
 SET temp_value = 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it looks like you're putting the update statement in the source for a report - that raises this type of error message.
I suggest you use the wizard to create a page of the type "Report with form". APEX will then generate everything for you, no manual update statements needed - it saves you a ton of time and the code is rock solid.

If you do want to write the update statement yourself, then that should be done in a "Page Process" with processing point "After Submit".